# robot_localization wrong output

Tags: navigation, ekf, odometry, pose, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to use an ekf_localization_node to fuse two sensors, odometry and pose, with the package robot_localization, in two dimensions. However, the output (published in the topic /odometry/filtered) seems to be wrong, since it is constantly moving and rotating even when the robot is still. Moreover, the odometry is always 0 without error, because I am using rqt_publisher to manually publish the topic /example/odom.

When I move the robot, the output follows that move, but when the robot doesn't move anymore, the output continues with that last movement. For example, if I twist the robot clockwise, the output is also twisted clockwise with the same velocity. However, when I stop twisting the robot, the output keeps twisting forever with the same velocity. The same happens with possition: if I move the robot forward, the output continues moving forever with the same velocity.

Can you help me with this?

I am new in ROS, so maybe I didn't understand some basic concepts.

You will find the launch file and the YAML file below, as well as some examples of the topics published. As I said, I am new in ROS, so I can't upload files yet. I'll copy-paste them. I can't upload an image of the output of the 'rosrun rqt_tf_tree rqt_tf_tree' command, but I can tell you that odom is linked to base_link, and the children of base_link are odometry and pozyx_frame.

This is the YAML file:

```
    frequency: 30
sensor_timeout: 0.1
two_d_mode: true
transform_time_offset: 0.0

transform_timeout: 0.0
print_diagnostics: true

debug: true
debug_out_file: /path/to/debug/file.txt
publish_tf: true
publish_acceleration: false



map_frame: map              # Defaults to "map" if unspecified
odom_frame: odom            # Defaults to "odom" if unspecified
base_link_frame: base_link  # Defaults to "base_link" if unspecified
world_frame: odom           # Defaults to the value of odom_frame if unspecified


odom0: example/odom
odom0_config: [true,  true,  false,
               false, false, false,
               true, true, false,
               false, false, true,
               true, true, false]
odom0_queue_size: 2

odom0_nodelay: false
odom0_differential: false

odom0_pose_rejection_threshold: 5
odom0_twist_rejection_threshold: 1


pose0: /pozyx_pose
pose0_config: [true,  true,  false,
               false, false, true,
               false, false, false,
               false, false, false,
               false, false, false]
pose0_differential: false
pose0_relative: true
pose0_queue_size: 5
pose0_nodelay: false


use_control: false
stamped_control: false
control_timeout: 0.2
control_config: [false, false, false, false, false, false]
acceleration_limits: [1.3, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.4]
deceleration_limits: [1.3, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4.5]
acceleration_gains: [0.8, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.9]
deceleration_gains: [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]

process_noise_covariance: [0.5, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                           0,    0.5, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                           0,    0,    0.06, 0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                           0,    0,    0,    0.03, 0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                           0,    0,    0,    0,    0.03, 0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0.5, 0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0.025, 0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0.025, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0.04, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0.01, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0.01, 0,    0,    0,    0,
                           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0.02, 0,    0,    0,
                           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0.01, 0,    0,
                           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0.01, 0,
                           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0.015]

initial_estimate_covariance: [1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9, 0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9,  0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     1e-9,  0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     1e-9,  0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     1e-9, 0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    1e-9, 0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    1e-9]
```

This is the Launch file:

```
<launch>
  <node pkg="robot_localization" type="ekf_localization_node" name="ekf_pozyx_node" clear_params="true">
    <rosparam command="load" file="$(find robot_localization)/params/pozyx_with_odometry.yaml" />
  </node>
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="link1_broadcaster" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 1 base_link pozyx_frame 100" />
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="link1_broadcaster2" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 1 base_link odometry 100" />
```

This is an example of the /example/odom topic:

```
header: 
  seq: 3778
  stamp: 
    secs: 1490951758
    nsecs: 889832960
  frame_id: odometry
child_frame_id: ''
pose: 
  pose: 
    position: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
    orientation: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
      w: 1.0
  covariance: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
twist: 
  twist: 
    linear: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
    angular: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
  covariance: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

This is an example of the /pozyx/pose topic (in metres):

```
header: 
  seq: 710
  stamp: 
    secs: 1490952053
    nsecs: 438256025
  frame_id: pozyx_frame
pose: 
  pose: 
    position: 
      x: 2.793
      y: 3.594
      z: 0.273
    orientation: 
      x: 0.708984375
      y: -0.0828247070312
      z: -0.0585327148438
      w: 0.697937011719
  covariance: [0.333, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.862, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.022, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.24]
```

**UPDATE 1**

Maybe it helps to know that the topic /diagnostics is echoing the following:

```
header: 
  seq: 162
  stamp: 
    secs: 1490956476
    nsecs: 738717851
  frame_id: ''
status: 
  - 
    level: 1
    name: ekf_pozyx_node: Filter diagnostic updater
    message: Potentially erroneous data or settings detected for a robot_localization state estimation node.
    hardware_id: none
    values: 
      - 
        key: X_configuration
        value: 2 absolute pose inputs detected for X. This may result in oscillations. Please ensure that your variances for each measured variable are set appropriately.
      - 
        key: Y_configuration
        value: 2 absolute pose inputs detected for Y. This may result in oscillations. Please ensure that your variances for each measured variable are set appropriately.
      - 
        key: odom0_pose_covariance
        value: The covariance at position (7), which corresponds to Y variance, was zero. This will be replaced with a small value to maintain filter stability, but should be corrected at the message origin node.
      - 
        key: pose0_covariance
        value: The covariance at position (35), which corresponds to YAW variance, was negative. This will be replaced with a small positive value to maintain filter stability, but should be corrected at the message origin node.
  - 
    level: 0
    name: ekf_pozyx_node: odometry/filtered topic status
    message: Desired frequency met
    hardware_id: none
    values: 
      - 
        key: Events in window
        value: 305
      - 
        key: Events since startup
        value: 4901
      - 
        key: Duration of window (s)
        value: 10.167694
      - 
        key: Actual frequency (Hz)
        value: 29.996967
      - 
        key: Minimum acceptable frequency (Hz)
        value: 25.200000
      - 
        key: Maximum acceptable frequency (Hz)
        value: 35.200000
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/258330/robot_localization-wrong-output/) by [Roman Portela](https://answers.ros.org/users/29883/roman-portela/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-03-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A bunch of things:

1. Turn off `debug` mode. It won't be able to write to that file anyway, but it should still be `false`.
2. For `example/odom`, you have the `frame_id` in your message set to *odometry*, yet your `world_frame` for the EKF is set to *odom*. You need to make the `frame_id` in `example/odom` *odom*, or provide an *odometry*->*odom* transform.
3. Moreover, for `example/odom`, you have no `child_frame_id` set, yet you are trying to fuse the velocity data from it.
4. Remove `odom0_pose_rejection_threshold` and  `odom0_twist_rejection_threshold`. Those are advanced parameters that should not be used until everything else is functioning as you expect (I rarely use them).
5. The diagnostics topic has some valuable information. You set `X` and `Y` to true in the EKF for both `odom0` and `pose0`, and they clearly don't agree, so the output going to behave very strangely.
6. If you already have a valid source of pose data (`pose0`), why are you feeding the filter fake odometry messages? It seems to me that you should just get rid of `odom0`.

I would recommend reviewing the `tf` [wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/tf) and the `r_l` [wiki](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/robot_localization/html/index.html) as well.

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2017-05-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0